# Determine why visual studio optimized out a function?

Tags: optimization, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Background:
I have a function that seems to have been optimized out in release builds in visual studio 2017.   It has some substantial processing, but tracing skips right over the call and trying to set a break-point inside the function says it's not available.

Question:
Is there a setting in VS2017 to cause it to output diagnostic information about why it optimized out a function call?

TIA!!

Comment: `It has some substantial processing` So, does that processing happen or not? If it does then the code wasn't "*optimized out*" and the breakpoints are unavailable for other reasons (missing/outdated symbols etc).

Comment: Of course not, I'm pointing out the function has substantial processing not a line or two, it's not called at all.  I worked around it by turning off optimizations for the function, but I'd rather know why it thinks it can optimize it out.

Comment: `Of course not` Is it ever called in the source code? If not see [`/OPT:NOREF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations?view=vs-2019), otherwise consider posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)..

Comment: debug mode works fine, release doesn't.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. If the function is never actually called then it will be dropped from release builds but preserved in debug ones. If it is called in both builds but somehow replaced with a no-op in the release build (since you say the "*substantial processing*" doesn't happen) then you just discovered a major bug in the toolset. That's quite unlikely, though, and you would need to show some hard evidence to make that case i.e. the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code.

Comment: The function is needed to work proper, the debug works, release doesn't, because it's optimized out.   Wrapped it with option to not optimize the function, now release works.  Wouldn't be the first time I've found bugs in MSVC, found a bunch of them, reported and some fixed some say they won't fix.

Comment: The chances that MSVC decides out of the blues to `nop` out an entire function that performs "*substantial processing*" are virtually zero, and just claiming that it happens is no proof. But if you are happy with the "solution" of disabling optimizations instead of figuring out what the real problem is then, fine, only you might as well delete the question since it's not going to help anyone else.

Comment: The question is if MSVC has a way to output diagnostic information to determine why it optimized it out.

Comment: The function could not have been just "*optimized out*" if it was indeed called at any point in the code, otherwise you'd get a [LNK2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=vs-2019). So it is either not referenced, in which case, yes, it *will* be optimized out of the release build as documented in the link I posted in a previous comment, or else it is present in the binary but you look for it in the wrong place. It is pointless to try and second-guess which of the two since you provided no code or context whatsoever.